# How to configure logging handler to produce weekly rotated log files?

Tags: python, logging

```
TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename, when='W', interval=0, backupCount=0)
```

Produces:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'fichierSemaineStandard': You must specify a day for weekly rollover from 0 to 6 (0 is Monday): W
```

But the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) tells

> value: 'W', type of interval: Week day (0=Monday)

So what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this section of documentation is not clear about this. After having a peek in the code, to make the week rotation work, the 'W' argument is not sufficient. The weekday number must be placed just after the letter `W`:

```
TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename, when='W0', backupCount=0)
```

Note that the "interval" argument is useless.